# How to make a POST request from Angular to Flask server

Tags: python, angular, flask

I'm working on an application that requires me to upload csv files to a FLASK server from an Angular frontend. i am having difficulties doing that. how can i connect the angular frontend to the backend flask server.

**Here's my component.html**

```
<div [hidden] = "submitted">
<form (ngSubmite) = "onSubmit()" action = "http://localhost:5000" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    <input type="file" name="file" />  
    <input type = "submit" value="Upload">  
</form>
```

**Here's my component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
selector: 'app-upload',
templateUrl: './upload.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./upload.component.css']
})


export class UploadComponent implements OnInit {

submitted = false;

constructor() { }

onSubmit(){
this.submitted = true;

}

ngOnInit() {
}

}
```

**here's my flask server**

```
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
@app.route('/upload' , method = ['GET' ,'POST'])
def upload_File():

if request.method == 'POST':
    #check if the psot request has the file part
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        flash('No file part')
        return redirect(request.url)
    file = request.files['file']
    #if the user does not select file , browser alsos 
    #submite an empty part without filename
    if file.filename == ' ':
        flash('No selected file')

     filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
     file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
     #return render_template('success.html', name = filename) 
    return redirect(request.url)
   return 'File Uploaded'
```

Comment: there is a doc that explain how to do simple http calls : https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 0):

1. Import `HttpClientModule` in your `AppModule`'s `imports`.
2. Inject `HttpClient` in your component (move that logic into a service later) like this `constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {}`
3. And finally in your submit method you can do an http request `this.http.post(url, body).subscribe()`